# What is this type of plot called and is there a function in R to create such a plot?

Tags: r, plot, scatter

I wish to make a plot like the one I have attached. For each patient I have a column with their lab values and I also have an `event` variable (1/0) that I wish to split similar to how each box is split by event in the picture.

I don't really need help with the coding as I can search for how to do it but currently I don't even know what to search for. It looks similar to a scatter box plot but there is no box plot in there (which I don't want too).

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Serology plot]

Comment: These are just a series of scatter plots. The lines are additional segment lines.

Comment: Thank you Chris! After searching for the function I assume they get some "width" to the scatter points by using jitter dodges.